# Can't connect to nodejs server on oracle compute instance

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

total noob to cloud services

vm image is ubuntu

tried entering into browser 192.18.132.24:3000

express app

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express(); 

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    return res.json({"Hello World": "Hi"});
})

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log('server listening on port 3000')
})
```

I have tried setting ingress rules on the subnet

`0.0.0.0/0  TCP 80`
`0.0.0.0/0  TCP 443`

I'm wondering if this has anything to do with the firewall. I looked at `sudo ufw app list` but all I can see is `openssh`